# how to make sbt-assembly case sensitive

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

my project uses an un-managed fat jar file.
on this file there are some classes that differ only by the case 
for instance it might have ABC.class and Abc.class

when I use sbt-assembly it outputs only one of the classes. is there any way letting the assembly keep both files?

Comment: what version of the sbt-assembly are you using?

Comment: 0.14.0
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.0")